# C Why is passing the address of this volatile variable failing

Tags: c, volatile

I have what I thought was rather simple code, I have a volatile variable, data, that my i2c hardware will write a byte to when it comes in.  So in my init function I have:

```
volatile unsigned char data;
data = 0x55;
i2c_write(I2C_ADDR, ENABLE, 1, &data);
```

The function prototype for the i2c_write function is:

```
void i2c_write(unsigned char dev_address, unsigned char reg_address, unsigned char len, volatile unsigned char *data);
```

This worked fine when data was unsigned char for both of them, but when I realized I forgot to make them volatile, I started getting the compiler message:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>
> #169 argument of type "volatile unsigned char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned char *"

Now I made them both volatile unsigned char, I'm not sure why this doesn't work.  I suspect maybe I'm about to learn that you can't do this with volatiles for some reason :)  So what did I do wrong?  This is for TI CC studio.

Comment: What makes you think that buffer needs to be marked `volatile`?

Comment: The code is OK. Check if you have changed all declarations of the function.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart "hardware will write a byte".

Comment: @n.m. I see that, but he's passing it to `i2c_write`, in which the CPU will presumably *read* the data.  `volatile` really only makes sense for global variables that are going to be updated by an interrupt handler.  [`volatile_considered_harmful.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/volatile-considered-harmful.txt) from the Linux kernel is a good read. TL;DR: `volatile` is insufficient in many scenarios as it only prevents things being cached in registers. It *doesn't* prevent re-ordering, by the CPU or the compiler.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm not sure why you think `data` is not such a variable.

Comment: Because again, `i2c_write` is presumably going to *write* data *out* the I2C bus, after *reading* it from the provided buffer. In this example, how is `data` going to change before any other code sees it?

Comment: The question is unclear ... if `i2c_write` expects `volatile unsigned char *data`, and you call it with the addess of `volatile unsigned char`, then there is no error.  The error message must be coming from a different line. Is #169 a line number?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart assuming that i2c_write is not an interrupt handler... wait, why assume that?

Comment: @n.m. Because it takes parameters. And it *looks* like an API to the i2c hardware. (e.g. [1](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/cris/arch-v32/drivers/i2c.h#L5), [2](https://github.com/LawrenceJones/raspi-gpio/blob/master/src/i2c/i2c_write.c), [3](http://www.zilogic.com/releases/current/zdev-user-manual/API-i2c-write.html) )

Comment: @n.m. Thank you that was the answer, I had not declared it correctly in the header file, only in the implementation and the call from main.   Everyone else, sorry for the ambiguity caused by using i2c_write, I just picked it as an example I also have an i2c_read that relies on volatile more.

Answer (score 2):

I would write the code like this, without `volatile` on any of the I2C APIs, although I'm open to arguments indicating why this is wrong.

```
volatile unsigned char g_buf[100];

void i2c_read(void *buf, size_t len)
{
     // ...
}

void i2c_interrupt_handler(void)
{
    // i2c_read is going to write to the buffer,
    // so we can cast away the `volatile`
    i2c_read((void*)g_buf, 1); 
}
```

Comment: @R.. I'm not surprised. If one had a `volatile` buffer like `g_buf` here, how would one pass it to a fixed API like `i2c_read` here, and not cast away the `volatile`?

Comment: You can't. You'd need to read to a temp buffer then use a for loop (not memcpy) to copy.

Comment: @R.. That seems terribly inefficient, for little *actual* gain.

Comment: It is a tangible gain if you actually need volatile semantics. `i2c_read` could store in any order since the lvalues it uses are not volatile. If you don't need volatile semantics then remove the volatile keyword.